# Get "blob" Data generated by "pdfmake" js library and Send it to Server via ajax (Laravel Controller)

Tags: javascript, ajax, blob, jspdf, pdfmake

I have a JavaScript function that generates PDF file using "jsPDF" : (works fine)

```js
var doc = new jsPDF("p", "mm", "a4");
doc.addImage(data, 'JPEG', 10, 10, 280, 140);
var blob = doc.output('blob');

var formData = new FormData();
formData.append('pdf', blob);
formData.append('current_id', carikodu);

$.ajaxSetup({
    headers: {
        'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
    }
});

$.ajax({
    type:'POST',
    url:'/mydestination',
    data: formData,
    processData: false,
    contentType: false,
    success: function(data){console.log(data)},
    error: function(data){console.log(data)}
});
```

but unfortunately "jsPDF" doesn't support UTF-8 properly. Then I decided to use "pdfmake", Instead.

```js
var docDefinition = {
    content: [{
        image: data,
        width: 500,
    }]
};
var doc = pdfMake.createPdf(docDefinition);
var blob;

doc.getBlob((blob) => {
    blob = new Blob([blob]);
});

var formData = new FormData();
formData.append('pdf', blob);
formData.append('current_id', carikodu);

$.ajaxSetup({
    headers: {
        'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
    }
});

$.ajax({
    type:'POST',
    url:'/mydestination',
    data: formData,
    processData: false,
    contentType: false,
    success: function(data){console.log(data)},
    error: function(data){console.log(data)}
});
```

I'm not sure if i'm using the "pdfmake" correctly but according to the documentation:
https://pdfmake.github.io/docs/getting-started/client-side/methods/#get-the-pdf-as-blob
In order to get pdf as Blob the way i did it with jsPDF, it needs to be like this:

```js
const pdfDocGenerator = pdfMake.createPdf(docDefinition);
pdfDocGenerator.getBlob((blob) => {
    // ...
});
```

The main issue here is that I get "Error 500" In server when i use "pdfmake"

```php
{message: "Undefined index: pdf", exception: "ErrorException",…}
exception: "ErrorException"
file: "/home2/myapp/app/Http/Controllers/MyController.php"
line: 44
message: "Undefined index: pdf"
```

Here is the code in my Laravel controller:

```php
$fileNameToStore = 'defaultname'.'_'.time().'.'.'pdf';

move_uploaded_file(
    $_FILES['pdf']['tmp_name'],
    $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/pdfdocs/".$fileNameToStore //line44
);
```